# AnyObject doesn't recognize proper functions when called

Tags: ios, swift

I have a protocol StateMachineDelegate, a class DataSource that conforms to it, and a class StateMachine that has a delegate with such protocol

Both classes implement a function found on the protocol so that if the class has a delegate, let them handle the functions; otherwise the class handles it itself.

StateMachine contains a function like this:

```
  func target() -> AnyObject {
    return delegate ?? self
  }
```

My full code goes like this:

```
import Foundation

@objc protocol StateMachineDelegate {

  optional func stateWillChange()
  optional func stateDidChange()

  optional func missingTransitionFromState(fromState: String?, toState: String?) -> String

}

class StateMachine {

  var delegate: StateMachineDelegate?

  func target() -> AnyObject {
    return delegate ?? self
  }

  func missingTransitionFromState(fromState: String, toState: String) -> String {
    return "Hello"
  }
}

class DataSource: StateMachineDelegate {

  func missingTransitionFromState(fromState: String?, toState: String?) -> String {
    return "Hi"
  }

}
```

When I was running some tests in playground and the StateMachine instance did not possess a delegate the target function returned the same instance as AnyObject. But once I called missingTransitionFromState from target it crashed so I change it to missingTransitionFromState?() with returned nil

Last function line should have returned "Hello"

Once delegate was given the target returned the delegateObject and proceeded to run the function as normal

The playground test are these:
[image]

Comment: casting target as a StateMachine in the last line causes it to output hello. not sure why that is

Comment: Yeah it worked that way. Most likely a bug, maybe. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All of your calls to missingTransitionFromState have a ? at the end except for the last one that won't execute. Replacing the ! with a ? fixes the problem. I didn't really understand what the code is doing but the question mark fixes it.

Comment: the question mark fixes the error, but returns nil which means that target does not implement said function. target is known to exist and that it is a StateMachine instance so it should return "Hello"

Answer (score 0):

Making the following changes fixes the problem:

1. Annotating `StateMachine`'s `missingTransitionFromState` method with `dynamic`
2. Changing the parameter types in `StateMachine`'s `missingTransitionFromState` method from `String` to `String?`, to match the signature of the other `missingTransitionFromState` method.

I believe that the method needs `dynamic` or `@objc` in order to be able to be called dynamically using `AnyObject`. However, after adding that, the compiler will complain that calls to `missingTransitionFromState` on an `AnyObject` is ambiguous, because there are two signatures, so you have to fix the signature.